# Load data from HDFS -Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a self contained application with SBT, and I want load my data from HDFS,I used this command:

```
val loadfiles1 = sc.textFile("hdfs:///tmp/MySimpleProject/file1.dat")
```

but an error it genere like this:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/tmp/MyProjectSpark/file1.dat
java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/tmp/MyProjectSpark/file1.dat
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1930)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1134)
        at app$.main(App.scala:33)
        at app.main(App.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
16/12/23 15:19:16 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1249)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)
16/12/23 15:19:16 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:996)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
        at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1249)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
16/12/23 15:19:16 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed Dec 23, 2016 3:19:17 PM
16/12/23 15:19:17 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
16/12/23 15:19:17 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/12/23 15:19:17 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-515b242b-7450-4215-9831-8e6976cb41ba
16/12/23 15:19:17 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-515b242b-7450-4215-9831-8e6976cb41ba/userFiles-ee18e822-55c7-4613-b3f7-03e5a4c896e1
```

Why all this error, just I want load a file from HDFS.
The configuration of the spark context is the following:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My first project hadoop spark").setMaster("local[4]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

And the configuration of the hdfs in the file site-core.xml is the following:

```
<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need 3 slashes at the start (or just 2)? `///`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacktrace says it clearly that

> Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/tmp/MyProjectSpark/file1.dat

Please specify hdfs namenode host and optional port(default 8020, specify if it is different).

Something like this(assuming localhost is your namenode):

> hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/MyProjectSpark/file1.dat

Comment: this was already [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32197116/647053) in the link comment. Ths is duplicate

Comment: Thank you. can you tell me how I can know the number of servers is runing my application, how I access or to see them, because I learned it exist a Spark UI (user interface) by http://<driver-node>:4040 I can modify the size of memory of executor and driver and I can see my cluster. I tried by this command on URL: http://127.0.0.1:4040 but the page is inaccessible. How I can know my driver-node. Thank you.

Comment: In spark UI, you can see all the executors used by your job. The Executor ID/host column shows which node/server that executor is running on. Go to executor tab above(the last tab) and the last entry will tell you where the driver is running.

Comment: Thank you, but excuse me, you told me "Go to executor tab above(the last tab)" how I can access to the executor tab ? by this address 127.0.0.1:4040 ? because I'm using the Apache Ambari as part of the Hortonworks Data Platform to access on my data in HDFS. Thank you.

Comment: According my resaerch, I can monitoring spark application using the spark Web UI, my problem is how I can access to this interface ?

Comment: I meant in the spark web UI, which by default runs on 4040 port. I am not sure about ambari though.